# Elastic Load Balancer and jmeter http(s) test script recorder

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, amazon-elb

I have an elastic load balancer(ELB) which distributes the load to two web servers. I have two more servers for the database with active-passive configuration. I have used JMeter's test script recorder for recording browser activity. For this, I have used http://elb-address/demo.html in the Firefox address box. Unfortunately, my recording controller would only take one web server.

I want to re-run this with multiple thread groups. But, when I specify http://elb-address/demo.html it will only use one web server IP address.

[image]

How to instruct the load balancer to use multiple web servers. Please advise how to proceed.

Comment: It may be connected to sticky-sessions configuration see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-sticky-sessions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Search and Replace](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54525) feature to replace all occurrences of the `web-server-ip-address` with `elb-address` in the recorded [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers

[image: JMeter Search and Replace]

Also make sure to add [DNS Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#DNS_Cache_Manager) to your Test Plan as JMeter might cache DNS requests so you will be hitting only one node behind the load balancer instead of distributing the load across backend nodes.